# Unable to translate Unicode character \\uDDDD

Tags: postgresql

I write data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL v15 database using c# app. When port a table with nvarchar(MAX) field to TEXT I receive an error

```
Unable to translate Unicode character \\uDDDD at index 438 to specified code page.
```

I have checked my PostgreSQL database, it has :

```
Encoding: UTF8
Collation: English_United States 1252
Character type: English_United States 1252
```

What can I do in that case?

Comment: Don't store Unicode text in non-Unicode tables. `nvarchar` is Unicode. C# strings are Unicode.

Comment: U+DDDD isn't a single character in itself - it's a low surrogate, which is only valid within a surrogate pair. What does your C# code look like, and what is the text value you're actually trying to migrate?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `nvarchar` = `varchar` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe provided UTF8 is really used. If that was the case there wouldn't be an error - unless the code did something really weird, like try to read and write the text as raw bytes. The OP mentions `English_United States 1252` twice. Of course that's not a valid PostgreSQL encoding name, Windows collation name or .NET CultureInfo either. *Somewhere*, something is trying to read Unicode as a single-byte codepage.

Comment: The English_United States 1252 - is PostgreSQL parameter. But this is the Windows PostgreSQL server. But anyway: how to fix the error? What should  I change the in PG db?

Comment: @JonSkeet :  my app reads rows from SQL Server db then insert row to PostgreSQL database. It is in c# loop record by record. But when I tried to find that character - nothing like "DDDD"

Comment: I suggest you add more diagnostics, or step through it record by record, so you can find the problematic record and check what text is causing a problem.